# Pending intent in notification not working

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

Below is my block of code which should open `NotificationActivity` when the notification is tapped on. But its not working.

```
private void setNotification(String notificationMessage) {
    Uri alarmSound = getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    mNotificationManager  = getApplication().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationActivity2.class);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
    .setContentTitle("My Notification")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(notificationMessage))
    .setContentText(notificationMessage).setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: Have you check with current time instead of NOTIFICATION_ID?

Comment: Is `NotificationActivity2` in your manifest?

Comment: Solved with adding system time as ID. thanks piyush..and all others who tried helping me :)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

try this:

```
private void setNotification(String notificationMessage) {

//**add this line**
int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

Uri alarmSound = getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
mNotificationManager  = getApplication().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationActivity2.class);

//**add this line**
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); 

//**edit this line to put requestID as requestCode**
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
.setContentTitle("My Notification")
.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
.bigText(notificationMessage))
.setContentText(notificationMessage).setAutoCancel(true);
mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: Can you give a reason why this works... this is extremely vague.

Comment: Worked for me aswell. Just passing a requestCode different than zero did the job. I'm only adding the flag: intent.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: Thank you stackoverflow Gods for this!

Comment: Confirmed this helped me as well. I solved a similar problem with a Samsung Galaxy S3 running 4.4.2 by changing the second parameter (requestCode) to PendingIntent.getService from a 0 to a 1.

Comment: Worked for me, check the lines below the **add this line** and compare it to the code block in the start post. 
Don't know why it works, but hey, it's android so that is nothing new.

Comment: @droidx This single line saved my days `int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();`. Thank you

Comment: notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
was the star!

Answer (score 13):

You might be using a notification id equal to 0. There is known issue with notification id being 0. If you will use any other id, it should work.

Comment: i didn't understand, should it be 0 or not? You are saying 'must be 0' and 'any other id should work' ??

Comment: I was guessing that the problem is that he must be using '0' which is causing the issue. It should not be 0 but any other id

Answer (score 7):

I added task builder and the below block code worked for me

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(SplashActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: I'm doing the same and it works. But - what if I want to have two different actions? I.e. content action and button action. How to create second pending intent?

Comment: @Micer You can create them separately and assign them in the respective methods.

Answer (score 3):

Try checking your `AndroidManifest.xml`, double check if you are navigating to an activity with an `intent-filter main action, launcher category`

For example,

[image]

I couldn't make my `pending intent` to navigate to `HomeActivity` but it works when navigating to `SplashScreen`

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helps, but I'm not sure how to solve this if you do in fact want to navigate to "HomeActivity". Should we add the activity to one of the filters? Or specify an action? Or add an action to the intent-filter?

Comment: Coincidentally, it turns out my "activity" wasn't listed in this list, because it was only a subview of another activity. This was the issue in the end. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

If the app is already running then you need to handle it in `onNewIntent`

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    //Handle intent here...
}
```

Comment: Use setIntent() update the intent values
`setIntent(intent);`

Answer (score 2):

Added the requestid, but the intent was still not opening.

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Setting those flags to clear the activities below the intent activity.