# Notification sent via PendingIntent does not show up

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

In one of `Activity`-derived class methods I'm trying to send a `Notification`, clicking on which will bring the Activity to foreground if my app is in background (not visible) right now. There are reasons why I don't use Service, but use Activity (that will hold `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`) for that.

I remember `Notification` worked for me when I used it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21204851/827880), but I sent it from Service. Now when I send it from Activity method and it doesn't show up, though I hear its notification sound.

So are there any reasons that prevent `Notification` show up sent from `Activity` method and how can it be solved?

Thank you.

Comment: Could it possibly be [Doze](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) related?

Comment: You need to provide code in order for people to help.  Have you added any logging?  Is the system dropping your `Intent` for some reason?  There's nothing inherent to notifications which prevent a one set by an activity from raising the activity.  Is your activity receiving the intent but it is not being handled properly?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have not noticed the warning in logcat, I thought if it doesn't crash that I'm good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not exactly precise copying `Notification` code sample. I removed `setSmallIcon()` call from code as I was too lazy to add icons. As a result system was really dropping my `Intent`, saying that no icon is provided for it and it'll be a crash in future releases.