# How to open specific activity after clicking on notification?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, firebase, android-notifications

I want to redirect ShowNotificationActivity after clicking on the notification. but when I click on it the app starts from the begining. how to solve this issue? here is the code.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

  private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

  private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;
  NotificationDatabaseHandler notificationDatabaseHandler;

  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
     Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

     if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

     // Check if message contains a notification payload.
     if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
     }

     // Check if message contains a data payload.
     if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        try {
           JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
           handleDataMessage(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
     }
  }

  private void handleNotification(String message) {
     if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
        // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

        // play notification sound
        NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
     }else{
        // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
     }
  }

  private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
     Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

     try {
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

        String title = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("message");

        boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
        String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
        String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
        JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

        Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
        Log.e("yes", "message: " + message);
        Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
        Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
        Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
        Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);

        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
           // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
           Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
           pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
           LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

           // play notification sound
           NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
           notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();

        } else {
           // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
           Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShowNotificationActivity.class);
           resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);


           // check for image attachment
           if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
           } else {
               // image is present, show notification with image
               showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
           }
        }
     } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
     } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
     }
  }

  /**
   * Showing notification with text only
  */
  private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
     notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
     notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
  }

  /**
  * Showing notification with text and image
  */
  private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
     notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
     notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
  }
}
```

In another class.........................

```
public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, null);
}

public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message, final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    // Check for empty push message
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
        return;

    // notification icon
    final int icon = R.drawable.ic_notification;

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    mContext,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );
}
```

Comment: Use `PendingIntent` to open a specific activity when you click on notification. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881226/pending-intent-in-notification-not-working

Answer (score -1):

Hey Suraj it's simple

just add

```
resultIntent = (getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
```

second activity is which you want to call on notification click.

and it's done.

Answer (score -1):

When sending notification use following :

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
                .....;


Intent activityIntent = new Intent(mContext, ShowNotificationActivity.class);
            activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```