# I am sending Notification to all users ..users are getting notifications but activity is not starting on the click of notification

Tags: android, android-intent

I am sending notification through FCM to all users from my admin app , users are getting notifications but unable to open activity on the click of notification.
This is my Receiver for Incoming notification

```
private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification notification, Map<String, String> data) {
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon_large);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString("picture_url", data.get("picture_url"));
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        String CHANNEL_ID="01";
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
                .setContentText(notification.getBody())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                //.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.win))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentInfo("Hello")
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.theme))
                .setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 300)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_small);

        try {
            String picture_url = data.get("picture_url");
            if (picture_url != null && !"".equals(picture_url)) {
                URL url = new URL(picture_url);
                Bitmap bigPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                notificationBuilder.setStyle(
                    new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bigPicture).setSummaryText(notification.getBody())
                );
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            //CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);

            String name="Channel_001";
            String description="Channel Description";
            //String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            //NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        //NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

There is not any error in that operation, On the click of notification , Notification disappears, But it doesn't open an activity provided in intent.
Helpers Please Note= Mainactivity.java is the LAUNCHER activity in my project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pending intent in notification not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881226/pending-intent-in-notification-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

`Override` below in your `MainActivity`

```
 @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
       setIntent(intent);
       super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the notification id to something else than 0,
example

```
notificationManager.notify(System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationBuilder.build());
```